# Does the automated trading work correctly?

Tags: civilization-4, civ-4-colonization

**NOTE**: This pertains to the Civ4: Colonization expansion specifically.

A real game killer I've found with this game, is that it appears to not effectively allocate resources during the automated trading.

eg.

> I'll typically have one city that is producing tools, with an Iron
>   works, and a couple of blacksmiths.
>
> On this city, I'll tick the 'export' box for tools.
>
> All other cities need to import tools, so they can finish their
>   printing presses etc.  On these, I'll tick 'import' for tools.
>
> I create a few wagons, and off we go.

What I find, is that the tools simply won't make it to the other cities. 
They might all pile up in one city, for example.

Comment: I seem to remember the game being kind of dumb about these routes.  When arriving at a city, a wagon will take as many of the export item as it can, and transport it until it reaches an import city that is under its import threshold.  It will then drop as many of that good as it has, up to the import threshold.   Thus, many of your tools may be stuck in a wagon travelling between the export city and an import city that isn't using them up.

Comment: wait - 'import threshold'? - I thought that value was an export threshold, ie. - 'Export tools from this city, but sure you always leave 30'.

Comment: Yeah, I think there is also an import threshold at the target city.  "Import tools to here, but only until this threshold is met" - it's been a while, though.  I'll have to load it up and try :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the game handles trade routes is a bit silly.  Essentially, having one city export a good to multiple import cities is fundamentally broken in the game.

If you mark a city as exporting a good, you can set a minimum threshold to keep in the city.  You can then mark a city to import that good.

Once you've done both of these, you assign a wagon train to handle the route.  The wagon train will:

- Go to the export city
- Load up on goods until it is full, the city is empty, or the export threshold is hit
- Go to the import city
- Dump all of the goods marked for inputs out of the wagon train

If you try to export from one city to two importers using 2 wagon trains, generally what will happen is that the first wagon train will arrive, take *all* of the good to export, go to the import city and dump it.  There's not even a check to see if it would overfill the warehouse - the wagon train just doesn't care.

Then the second wagon train arrives at the export city, sees there is none to be exported, and just sit around and wait, *perhaps* getting a few of the good as it is produced, assuming the first wagon train doesn't show up and steal it again.

The net result is that you have a pile of something in your first city, where you'd want that evenly distributed between the two.

One way to work around this is by having two legs to the trade route.

Say City A produces a good, and you need it in City B and City C.

- Have City A export the good
- Have City B import it *and* export it with a minimum threshold being how much of that good you want City B to keep.
- Have City C import the good

You can assign one wagon train to run both the A->B and the B->C routes, or you can assign 2 wagon trains.  The advantage to having 2 is that if City B rarely gets above the export threshold, City A might stockpile goods while the wagon train is waiting at B to run the B->C leg.

Overall, though, I suggest that if you need anything more complex than "move all of this over there" that you run the trade routes manually.

Comment: "Overall, though, I suggest that if you need anything more complex than "move all of this over there" that you run the trade routes manually." 

Yip, and this is what kills the game for me.

Answer (score -1):

if you set your importing cities to have an export with a value, they'll use that value as their import cap and materials will be exported to other locations after it fills